# Why is UIActionSheet is autodismissing?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I am using the following statement to dismiss UIActionsheet with UIPickerView, for which a closebutton has been defined.

```
[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

The UIActionsheet is auto-dismissing, before the closebutton can be clicked? One theory I have for why this is is because the UIActionsheet is called via a button press, and this button press is qualifying the UIActionsheet to dismiss right after it is enabled.  How do I ensure that the closebutton is the button whose index is referred to in the above statement? How do I find the index of the closebutton I have created programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Since `UIActionSheet` has no "`closebutton`" I'll assume you mean "`cancelButton`". You would do that like this:

```
[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[actionSheet cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];
```

Comment: I've actually added a close button. (below).  The code specified works with the 'cancel' button, but I don't want to use this with the UIPicker.UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];